# How to get daily market cap with yfinance for Python

Tags: yfinance

I'd like to get market cap for tickers on a daily basis. The code I compiled from other examples just show 1 data for each ticker.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

stocks = ['XP','STNE','PAGS']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','Marketcap'])
df.columns = ['Stock','Marketcap']

for stock in stocks: 
info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
marketcap = info['marketCap']    
df = df.append({'Stock':stock,'Marketcap':marketcap}, ignore_index=True)

display(df)
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. So far have not been successful. Doesn't have it in fastquant either. might be able to go through coinmarketcap's api though. seems like a hassle

Comment: it's been a year now, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Please use fast_info instead of info. Therefore your syntax should be like this:

```
for stock in stocks: 
    info = yf.Ticker(stock).fast_info
    marketcap = info['market_cap']
    df = df.append({'Stock':stock,'Marketcap':marketcap}, ignore_index=True)

display(df)
```

Then you should get be able to get back your market cap. Hope this help.